# Elasticsearch term query issue

Tags: elasticsearch

[image]

[image]

As the pictures show the record field of dispatchvoucher value is "True".
But when I searched with the term it couldn´t found any record.
when I changed the value to "true", the result matched. What's the reason for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the documentation :

> Avoid using the term query for text fields.
>
> By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields as part of
> analysis. This can make finding exact matches for text field values
> difficult.
>
> To search text field values, use the match query instead.

The [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is the default analyzer which is used if none is specified. It provides grammar-based tokenization.

```
GET /_analyze
    {
      "analyzer" : "standard",
      "text" : "True"
    }
```

The token generated is -

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "true", 
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**[Term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field. Since `True` gets tokenized to `true`, so when you are using the term query for `"dispatchvoucher": "True"`, it will not show any results.**

You can either change your index mapping to

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "dispatchvoucher": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

OR You need to add `.keyword` to the `dispatchvoucher` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after `dispatchvoucher` field).

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "dispatchvoucher": "True"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "dispatchvoucher.keyword": "True"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65605120",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "dispatchvoucher": "True"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @DavidDai did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: @DavidDai if my answer helped you resolve your issue, can you please upvote and accept my answer as well 